# Error while creating an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm a beginner in Android. So, I have an icon on clicking that an AlertDialog should appear. Simple.----android:onClick = "onCreateDialog"----

```
    package com.example.android.guardian;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onCreateDialog(View v) {
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.g_icon);
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                // Get the layout inflater
                LayoutInflater inflater = builder.getLayoutInflater();

                // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
                // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
                builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_g_pass, null))
                        // Add action buttons
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.SavePass, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // sign in the user ...
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            }
                        });
                builder.create();
            }

        });

    }
}
```

The above code is like a skeleton. No details. I want to implement the above function when clicked i.e to open an AlertDialog. It says *cannot resolve getLayoutInflater() method*  Strings.xml

Guardian

```
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_g_pass">Google</string>
<string name = "cancel">Cancel</string>
<string name = "savePass">Save</string>
```

this is the logcat

```
08-17 01:34:22.430  26909-26909/com.example.android.guardian E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.guardian, PID: 26909
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3829)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18457)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5047)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3824)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18457)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5047)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:563)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:260)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at com.example.android.guardian.MainActivity.onCreateDialog(MainActivity.java:60)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3824)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18457)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5047)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".g_pass"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_g_pass"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.android.guardian.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Do you want to open that dialog when clicking on that imageview?

Comment: Post your both xmls completely. You already posted some of it of the imageView that I wanted to see, but you have two activities, which one did you write your imageView in? Also why do you want to inflate the same layout of your activity to the AlertDialog? It should be different.

Comment: Did you fix your issue? It should work. Make sure you inflate other view in your AlertDialog. Don't inflate activity_main in your AlertDialog and you have already inflated it...

Comment: ImageView = activity_main; activity_g_pass = Hello world; how do i implement inflater for the activity_g_pass i have updated the above code but still not working

Comment: the problem with the code is in the AlertDialog.Builder method....instead of passing 'getApplicationContext()' just use 'this'.....it works....thanks a ton...cheers

Comment: Glad you have fixed your issue! Would you mind if you vote my answer up and mark it as correct please? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace it with this:

```
public void onCreateDialog(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.savePass, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // sign in the user ...
            }
        });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    }
}
```

This will open an AlertDialog when clicking an imageView. In your xml file where your imageView is in, add:

> android:onClick="onCreateDialog"
>
> android:clickable="true"

Then go to your strings.xml and change the string "SavePass" to "savePass".

Comment: Thank you. But the issue still remains. cannot resolve getLayoutInflater() method

Comment: Updated the answer, check it.

Comment: That worked. Could you please explain about the code you just edited?

Comment: I know why the app crashed. Actually my first answer was wrong but I have fixed it now... I hope. Reason of crashing is that you were just adding setOnClickListener to the imageView and not actually showing the dialog. Try the edited code now. Sorry :)

Comment: Weird. Can you please update your question with your xml code?

Comment: I updated the answer again. For some reason, you and I forgot to add @Override on your negative button. Try the above again... :)

Comment: Also fix the savePass string that I have mentioned. String names must begin with lower characters.